How to Change Parameter name of SQL function
I am trying to change the parameter name of an SQL function using an SQL command. ALTER FUNCTION seems possible but I'm unsure of the syntax. Here is the signature:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.schema.ADDONE("ARG1" FLOAT)

And I'm trying to change ARG1.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=statements-alter-function-compiled-sql-scalar says "The function options, parameter names, and routine body can be changed..." with ALTER FUNCTION.
Thanks

if the function is used, and working, renaming the parameter would also require renaming the use of that inside the function body. Where-as if it has never worked, you could just delete and create from scratch with a correct name. Seems a very strange place to be.

You can use ALTER FUNCTION to rename the parameter ARG1 to NEW_ARG1 specifies the parameter you want to rename and the new name for it.
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.schema.ADDONE(ARG1 FLOAT)
    RENAME PARAMETER ARG1 TO NEW_ARG1;


@David George appreciate if you could mark it as correct and give an up vote for the answer if it serves the purpose. Thanks in advance :-)

answer upvoted just because of the request for an upvote.  You're welcome.

@Selaka Nanayakkara This syntax did not work for me as I'm using snowflake. Do you know the syntax for snowflake?
